# Get text box value when I type the value by every key press

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to know get text box value when I type the value by every key press.

I have to get the value.

If I type numbers I have to get, so I have checking with that value.

Comment: It's really tiring to see how many users recommend using *onkeyup* for things like this.  It just reeks of unprofessionalism when something doesn't happen until I lift my finger off the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will have to serve events on input field: onkeypress, onkeyup, onkeydown, onpaste, onchange.

Comment: there is also `oninput` which does exactly what you want in all browsers but not MSIE (<=8.0)

Comment: `onpropertychange` in IE is as good as `oninput`, you just need to check `event.propertyName == "value"`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var my_input = document.getElementById('my_input');
my_input.onkeyup = function() {
  alert(my_input.value);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='my_input' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of an input element from its [`value` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp), e.g.

```
element.value
```

To execute some function on every key press, you should bind an [event handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) for the `keyup` event to this element.

You should make yourself familiar with event handling in JavaScript and the variations in the different browsers. The site I linked to (quirksmode.org) is a very good resource for that.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that in certain browsers the method by which you get the value of a textarea differs. I'm thinking in IE6, at least, it actually registers the value of a textarea as it's innerHTML (or the other way around).

Worth doing a check in you eventListener for if the value is set, or not, and checking the innerHTML if it's not, just in case!